# Need help Importing SQL file to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (no experience, web developer won't help)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

A web developer has given me files to upload the new website they've built for us. As we don't host the website with them they can't upload them for us.

With Fasthosts, all the files have been uploaded ok but the last step of importing the SQL file via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio keeps coming back with the same executing error messages, see errors below:

- Information 0x402090de: Data Flow Task 1: The total number of data rows processed for file "C:XX.sql: is 4733 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
- Error 0xc02020c5: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed while converting column "_MySQL dump 10 13 Distrib 5 7 15" (10) column " -- My SQL dump 10 13 Distrib 5 7 15" (45). The conversion returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
- Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The 'Data Conversion 0-0 Outputs[Data Conversion Output]. Columns[--My SQL dump 10 13 Distrib 5 7 15)"  failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Data Conversion 0 - 0. Outputs [Data Conversion Output[ Columns[--My SQL dump 10 13 Distrib 5 7 15]"  specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
- Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code
  DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion 0-0" (37) failed with error code 0xC020902A while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (38). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. There may be an error message posted before this with more information about the failure. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard).

I have searched for these errors and tried changing the columns from DT_STR to DT_TEXT, this didn't help. As mentioned in the title I'm no expert in this, never done this before.

Is there anyone that can help, amazing, or if it's a case of 'pay your web developer for the hosting every month' then so be it.

Thanks in advance.

Sophie

Comment: The error is telling you the problem: *'The conversion returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".'* there's truncation in the import process in your SSIS package.

Comment: Hi @Larnu thanks for pointing that out for me. As mentioned this is not my expertise at all (let me emphasise at all). Is this something that can be corrected during the upload process or is this an issue that I need to go back to the web developer with? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It depends where the error is occurring in the package, might be the database that needs changing, might be the package, might be the source data that needs to be made shorter; depends on the requirements.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for clarifying. I'll have to go back to the web developer to get this sorted then. Thanks again.